# If I assign a socket connection to a property, apply event listeners to that property and then assign another socket, will the listeners still work?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, socket.io

In the code below, I create a socket connection on `mounted()`, and assign it to the `socket` property, then I create a `this.socket.on` listener that listens for a `messageToClient` event from the server.

If I were to change the socket assigned to `this.socket` using the `@click` event on the `div`, would the `this.socket.on('messageToClient', (message) => {})` begin listening for `messageToClient` event on the new socket? Or would it keep listening for `messageToClient` event on the old original socket?

```html
<template>
    <div @click="socket = io('http://localhost:3000/test2')"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            socket: ''
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.socket = io('http://localhost:3000/test1')

        this.socket.on('messageToClient', (message) => {
            console.log(message)
        })

    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the newly created `socket` in the `click`-handler would not automatically listen to the event, so the handler should setup the new `socket`. You could declare a method that creates and initializes the `socket`, and then call the same method from `mounted()` and the `click`-handler:

```html
<template>
  <div @click="setupSocket('http://localhost:30000/test2')">Setup socket</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      socket: null,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.setupSocket('http://localhost:30000/test1')
  },
  methods: {
    setupSocket(url) {
      this.socket = io(url)
      this.socket.on(...)
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: I see, just out of curiosity, would using a watcher that watches the socket property and creates the this.socket.on(...) listeners every time the socket property changes achieve the same outcome as your code?